# Working with ASP.NET, C# and SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql, web

I have been given the task to create a shop website that allows users to look at DVDs that are available in a shop page and then when they click on one they will be taken to a details page which will give more information dynamically about the DVD. I also have been given a c# file which contains a class called DVD.
I have so far got the webpages which I made in ASP.NET and that was easy enough to pull everything from the database and it all works fine but that has nothing to do with the DVD.cs file.

Am I missing something obvious? I have to use this file which I will post below :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace DVDs
{
class DVD
{
    public string Title
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int Price
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public int YearReleased
    {
        get;
        set;
    }


    public string Desc
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public DVD(string title, int price, int yearReleased, string desc)
    {
        Title = title;
        Price = price;
        YearReleased = yearReleased;
        Desc = desc;

    }

    protected bool Save()
    {
        //add code to save to the database
        return true;
    }

    protected bool Load()
    {
        //add code to load from the database
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

Can someone please explain how I use these variables to link between the database and the .aspx file?

All help would be appreciated thanks

**EDIT**: Code tried so far

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    if (this.IsPostBack)
    {
        PageAsyncTask pat = new PageAsyncTask(BeginAsync, EndAsync, null, null, true);
        RegisterAsyncTask(pat);
    }
}

private IAsyncResult BeginAsync(object sender, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, object state)
{
    DVD dvd = new DVD();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question very much looks like some homework / school / studies stuff, which we won't solve for you in general. You are however welcome to post a question with a specific problem. So what exactly have you tried so far? Where exactly are you stuck? See also [How to ask](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: Where's this class come from? You say you were 'given' it? You also said you have been able to pull stuff out of the database already. Great. How? Show us this code.

Comment: it's not homework really its in a teach yourself ASP book which doesnt give answers. I have tried using this:
    `protected override void  OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        if (this.IsPostBack)
        {
            PageAsyncTask pat = new PageAsyncTask(BeginAsync, EndAsync, null, null, true);
            RegisterAsyncTask(pat);
        }
    }

    private IAsyncResult BeginAsync(object sender, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, object state)
    {
        DVD dvd = new DVD()
        {
            
        }`
but i am lost at what to do..its been stressing me out for days

Comment: sorry the code isnt formatted i cant seem to do it in a comment

Comment: @user1845575: You can edit your question and put the code you have in comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

either make it with MVC as it is already told or take a look at ASP.Net binding to link your DVD object to the UI.

This could be a good starting point: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307860

Answer (score -4):

Using entity framework will help you connect your class to database in a very easy way, but for linking your class properties to ASP.NET .aspx file you can use `session["key"] = value`